# Looking for a list of events that remove shapes from GoogleMap

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a program that, when stripped down to the barest features, draws polygons and circles to my `GoogleMap` as expected. However, with all other features added, the polygons and circles no longer show up on the map. Since there are a few thousand lines of code to comb through, I was searching for a comprehensive list of events that would cause shapes to be cleared from the map to narrow it down. I haven't been able to find any documentation on this in the official Google Maps documentation.

Is there a complete list somewhere that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found that there is only one event that removes shapes from a `GoogleMap`. That event is `GoogleMap.clear()`.